# SQL query to break down by day but also add values

Tags: mysql, sql

So the example here will be rather vague but it'll get the point across.

Let's say I have 3 stores and I want to know how much each store makes per day. Each day may have several transactions with in. I need to know the store #, date, amount made that day.

Ex Data would look like this:

```
Store # |  Date      | Transaction
--------+------------+------------
1234    | 2020-01-01 |         100
1234    | 2020-01-01 |          85
1235    | 2020-01-01 |          65
1235    | 2020-01-01 |          70
1234    | 2020-01-02 |          72
```

I am wanting it to break it down so I end up with

```
Store # |  Date      | Transaction
--------+------------+------------
1234    | 2020-01-01 |         185
```

I get that I can do

```
Select store_number, sum(transacton_amount)
from transactions
where date between '2020-01-01' and '2020-01-3'
```

but I'm lost on how I get it to do a break down by days, not just add it all together.

Hopefully it makes sense.

Comment: What DBMS are you using? Is this MySQL? The query is invalid, because you cannot select an aggregation (the sum of transaction amounts) and an unaggregated attribute at the same time without a `GROUP BY` clause. Date literals start with the key word `DATE`, by the way: `'2020-01-3'` is a string (which your DBMS may or may not be able to  convert into a date), whereas `DATE '2020-01-03'` is a date.

Comment: Your example is incomplete, I guess. You don't want one result row only for the five sample table rows, correct? Do you want three result rows, one per store and date in your table?

Comment: If this is MySQL, make sure to set `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY` mode. At least as long as you haven't mastered aggregation and `GROUP BY`. Thus you'd get an error on your query indicating that your mistake is the missing `GROUP BY` clause. (Please always tag SQL requests with the DBMS you are using.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to specify columns to group on, otherwise you only get a total `SUM()` for the columns matching your `WHERE` condition.

Simply add `GROUP BY store, date` to your query.

Comment: It's possible I love you and we now have to escape together. I've been staring at this for an hour.